# maven emma code coverage report

Tags: spring, maven, emma

I am using spring 3.1.0 version api for my project and i have created the test cases for all the layer(web,service,dao).

Execute the test case using mvn test ,it working fine (ie) all the test case are getting passed.

while i am trying to get the code coverage report using mvn emma:emma getting below error.

org.springframework.beans.beanutils.instantiateclass(ljava/lang/class ljava/lang/class)ljava/lang/object

in my  pom.xml

for : spring test

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
<version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

for : emma plugin

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
<artifactId>emma-maven-plugin</artifactId>
<version>1.0-alpha-3</version>
</dependency>
```

Please share you thoughts.

Regards
Vasanth D

Answer (score 2):

No need to add any plugin entry in your pom.xml, just run mvn emma:emma. You should be able to generated code coverage report successfully.